# Count multiple consecutive letters in a list in Scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, iteration, racket

So, I have been given the task to create a procedure that gives you two letters and a list, that need to be found in that list. I started writing the procedure, but soon stumbled upon some errors. The code I have is the following:

```
(define (count-2-consecutive x y lst)
      (define (iter ctr lst)
        (cond ((null? lst) '())
              ((and (eq? x (car lst)) (eq? y (cadr lst))) (count-2-consecutive x y (cdr lst)))
              (else (count-2-consecutive x y (cdr lst)))))
      (iter 0 lst))
```

So, when I try to run an example (such as: `(count-2-consecutive 'n 't '(h o t t e n t o t t e n t e n t e n))` I get a 'contract violation' error, pointing me at the `cadr` that I used in my code. If anyone could help me point out what I have done wrong, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `(cadr xs)` you need to know that the list `xs` has at least two elements. You use the test `(null? xs)` to make sure that the list `xs` has at one element. Add an extra clause in your cond with the test `(null? (cdr xs))` to handle one-element lists.

```
(define (count-2-consecutive x y lst)
      (define (iter ctr lst)
        (cond ((null? lst) '())
              ((null? (cdr lst)) SOMETHING)
              ((and (eq? x (car lst)) (eq? y (cadr lst))) (count-2-consecutive x y (cdr lst)))
              (else (count-2-consecutive x y (cdr lst)))))
      (iter 0 lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `for/sum` loop here:

```
(define (f x y l)
  (for/sum ((i (sub1 (length l)))
            #:when (and (equal? (list-ref l i) x)
                        (equal? (list-ref l (add1 i)) y)))
    1))
```

Testing:

```
(f 1 2 '(0 1 2 3 1 2 5))
(f 1 2 '(0 1 3 1 2 5))
(f 1 2 '(0 4 3 5 8))
```

Output:

```
2
1
0
```

One can also test using `take` function for lists to get a sublist of 2 items to compare with x and y:

```
(define (f x y l)
  (let loop ((l l)
             (cntr 0))
    (cond
      [(< (length l) 2)                 cntr]
      [(equal? (take l 2) (list x y))   (loop (rest l) (add1 cntr))]
      [else                             (loop (rest l) cntr)])))
```